# Maven creation of a WAR and an EAR containing that WAR as one module using classifier?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, classification, maven-war-plugin

I understand that this might sound like the wrong thing to do, but what I'm attempting is to have a Maven POM (module) that when installed will package as WAR but in addition, as an EAR that contains the single WAR.

To clarify: I am looking to wrap each existing WAR in my project in *its own* EAR.

The reason behind my desire is because I am looking at restructuring the way we package our released WARs so that each is contained within an EAR (but also still generate an independent WAR artifact for development ease). I am not keen to create a new module that depends on the WAR and package it in an EAR because I have loads of WARs.

Currently I am trying this, for one of my existing WAR modules, *without* success using a **classifier**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <parent>
        ...
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>se-index-webapp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    ...
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>search-index.ear</finalName>
                    <classifier>ear</classifier>
                    <unpackTypes>war</unpackTypes>
                    <modules>
                        <webModule>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
                            <uri>search-index.war</uri>
                            <bundleFileName>search-index.war</bundleFileName>
                            <contextRoot>/SearchIndex</contextRoot>
                        </webModule>
                    </modules>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>${artifactId}</artifactId>
                        <version>${project.version}</version>
                        <type>war</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>  
        ...
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I get the error:

```
Artifact[war:myproject:se-index-webapp] is not a dependency of the project
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: Consider having your pom.xml in your war project only deal with the war, and a separate "deploy-as-ear" pom.xml invoked when deploying.

Comment: If you are trying to having something cleaner, then this is not the way to go. To my knowledge what you are trying to do is not possible because you are implicitly creating an infinite dependency cycle. You may find better options on the Maven-user ML

Comment: At work we created a custom maven plugin that packages the projects dependencies and artifacts inside an ear and creates deployment descriptors based on the artifacts type. Together with a war plugin configured to create skinny wars this is working great.  The projects were initially created with oracles jdeveloper which uses similar pakcaging by default. I have to check if I can publish this somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you have to change is based on Maven conventions to have a separate EAR module which results in the following structure:

```
  +-- root (pom.xml)
       +--- mod-ear (pom.xml) packaging: ear
       +--- mod-war (pom.xml) packaging: war
```

Than you can define the dependencies to your mod-war module very simple by giving

```
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>..</groupId>
          <artifactId>..</artifactId>
          <version>..</version>
      </dependency>
   ...
  </dependencies>
```

The advantage of this approach that you have separated the information which belong to ear and them which belong to ear module.

The result is you can do a mvn clean package on the root level or do a mvn install / deploy which deploys war as well as ear into your repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I understand how to do this. However, I want to avoid additional modules just to wrap a single WAR in this EAR (because I have so many that I want to wrap in an EAR)

Comment: Whatever you like but you will start fighting with maven...;-) The number is not an argument...